# MAX File Size PHP MYSQL

Tags: mysql, blob

In my php.ini file my max size is 1 mb. However, when I insert a blob into my mysql database it cuts it off at 64 kb. How can I increase the file max size? Note: The image is literally cut off at 64 kb it displays a sliver of the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to consider a MEDIUMBLOB, or even a LONGBLOB. For when a standard BLOB with it's maximum size of just 64kb just won't do.

BLOB max sizes are listed [here](https://philihp.com/blog/2011/maximum-sizes-of-mysql-blob-fields/) :)

Comment: Thank you! Also, I appreciate the link!

Answer (score 0):

> If strict SQL mode is not enabled and you assign a value to a BLOB or
>   TEXT column that exceeds the column's maximum length, the value is
>   truncated to fit and a warning is generated

Change your `BLOB` type to  [`LONGBLOB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html)

Comment: Thanks! By the way what is the max size?